# Variable not updating based on a change of another

Tags: java

In my program I have a method calculateCost(), which gets the cost of a truck based on the minimum temperature of said truck.

```
public double calculateCost() {

    int minimumTemperature = this.getTemperature();

    System.out.println("Temp is: " + minimumTemperature);

    double costOfTruck = 900 + 200 * (Math.pow(0.7, (minimumTemperature / 5))); 

    System.out.println("Cost is: " + costOfTruck);

    return costOfTruck;
}
```

When this method is executed, the minimumTemperature correctly changes as shown in the console, however, the costOfTruck doesn't change when the minimumTemperature is changed.

Comment: division on integer types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `minimumTemperature` < 5 then `minimumTemperature / 5` will equal zero due to integer division and `Math.pow(0.7, (minimumTemperature / 5)` will equal 1, so try using a double numeric type

```
double costOfTruck = 900 + 200 * (Math.pow(0.7, (minimumTemperature / 5.0)));
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much!!